# Simulate if statement

Tags: prolog

What I'm trying to do is to write something on the console if any predicate is true.An example would be:

```
write('hello') IF member('a',['a','b']).
```

Comment: Search "prolog if" in the search box. Lots of posts on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

A conjunction `a, b` is true (succeeds) if `a` is true, and `b` is true. The order is significant:

> Write "hello" and check if `x` is in `[a,b]`

```
?- write(hello), member(x, [a,b]).
hello
false.
```

> Check if `x` is in `[a,b]`, and if it is, write "hello"

```
?- member(x, [a,b]), write(hello).
false.
```

> Check if `a` is in `[a,b]`, and if it is, write "hello"

```
?- member(a, [a,b]), write(hello).
hello % press Enter
true .
```

The if-then-else construct `Condition -> Then ; Else` is something slightly different and based on your question alone, I don't know if you really need it. For example, to avoid the extra choice point in these examples, you might want to write:

```
?- memberchk(a, [a,b]), write(hello).
hello
true.
```

Of course, you might actually need to look at each member. For example:

> Print out only the capital letters in a list of chars

```
?- member(X, [a, b, 'C', 'D', e, f, 'G']), char_type(X, upper).
X = 'C' ;
X = 'D' ;
X = 'G'.
```

You should look at this carefully. There is no if-then-else, nor printing. I'd almost say that you are trying to solve a non-problem. Very generally speaking, you shouldn't need if-then-else or printing with `write` or `format` too often.

The if-then-else can be avoided by using predicates that do it for you, as `member/2` vs. `memberchk/2` shown above.

The printing is done by the top level. I have trouble coming up with valid uses of `write` and `format`, unless you need to write to a file/stream. Even then, it is cleaner and easier to first get the final result ready, then write it to a file in one go.

Answer (score 0):

You could write:

```
 ?- member('a',['a','b']) -> write('hello').
 hello
 true.
```

or define a clause:

```
write:-member('a',['a','b']) -> write('hello').
```

and query:

```
?- write.
hello
true.
```