# how to convert -> into clauses in prolog

Tags: prolog

So I am working on a practice problem, where I need to find the number of cells with opening right, up , down and left. I have a working solution but I want to change it into clauses. I don't want to to use -> to define if and else. how can I fix the code below without the affecting the solution.

Here is the code:

```
stats(U,D,L,R) :- maze(Size,_,_,_,_),
             findall(R, genXY(Size,R), Out),

             statsHelp(Out,U, L, R, D).

statsHelp([],0,0,0,0).
statsHelp([[X|[Y]]|Tl],U, L, R, D) :- cell(X,Y,Dirs,Wt),
                            (contains1(u,Dirs) -> U1 is 1; U1 is 0), % how do i remove -> and separate them into clauses? 
                            (contains1(d,Dirs) -> D1 is 1; D1 is 0),
                            (contains1(l,Dirs) -> L1 is 1; L1 is 0),
                            (contains1(r,Dirs) -> R1 is 1; R1 is 0),
                            statsHelp(Tl,U2, L2, R2, D2),

                            U is U1 + U2,
                            D is D1 + D2,
                            R is R1 + R2,
                            L is L1 + L2.




contains1(V,[V|Tl]).
contains1(V,[Hd|Tl]):-
contains1(V,Tl).
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40035182/1812457). The question was closed as duplicate but it might be that the answer is useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your `contains1/2` predicate is just the standard `member/2`, which you could use instead.

As for a version that always succeeds and produces an extra 0 or 1, I think you have to use a cut or negation to achieve that. Here is one with negation:

```
member_reified(X, Xs, Result) :-
    member(X, Xs),
    Result = 1.
member_reified(X, Xs, Result) :-
    \+ member(X, Xs),
    Result = 0.
```

You could of course also just move your use of `->` into your definition of `member_reified/3`. Different implementations can give different trade-offs on backtracking; this one may succeed several times:

```
?- member_reified(x, [a, b, c], Result).
Result = 0.

?- member_reified(a, [a, b, c], Result).
Result = 1 ;
false.

?- member_reified(a, [a, b, c, a], Result).
Result = 1 ;
Result = 1 ;
false.
```